# Meaning of xml doc "see cref" M, F, T prefixes?

Tags: c#

Wha is the meaning of xml doc "see cref" M, F, T (maybe more) prefixes?

Examples: (taken from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior enum documentation)

```
<see cref="M:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated" />
<see cref="T:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext" />
<see cref="F:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefixes tell you what the reference is:

- **M** - Method
- **T** - Type
- **F** - Field

See [here for a full list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/processing-the-xml-file).